# Editing Matrix in Python results in Memory Problems

Tags: python, list, memory, memory-management

I'm currently trying to normalise a matrix of values. This list of lists is rather big (18.000 x 18.000) but creating it was no problem so far. I now wanted to normalise it, by dividing each entry with the sum of the row and the sum of the column, which should be easy, especially since the matrix is symmetrical.

This is my code for this task:

```
def normalise_labels(labels):
    sums = [sum(x) for x in labels]
    for i,row in enumerate(labels):
        for j,cell in enumerate(row):
            labels[i][j] = cell/(sums[i]*sums[j])
    return labels
```

This however always results in 
*Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9: SIGKILL)*

Most likely due to excessive memory usage.

I tracked the sizes of all local variables in each iteration and as expected they do not change, meaning that the `labels` variable is not getting bigger. The only thing that is changing, is the type of each element within the matrix from `int` to `float`, which should not change the used memory (28 byte for int and 24 byte for float).

I want to understand why this error keeps occurring. Does python create objects in the background when changing the elements of lists and this results in this excessive memory usage?

Also, do you have any ideas how I could implement this task without running into the same problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: As far as python's management of data: It is potentially keeping the original `labels` and by the time it returns, it has a second 2D array of the same size, doubling the necessary data

Comment: To improve on your design, I would start using [iterators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator), and [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20compre#list-comprehensions) to compute data as needed and not all at once

Comment: Also a fun way to turn a 2D array from row-wise to column-wise is to do `zip(*list)`

Comment: @AnthonyL I now tried it like this and still get the same error:
```labels = [cell/(sums[i]*sums[j]) for (i,row) in enumerate(labels) for (j,cell) in enumerate(row)]```
Do you think iterators and generators could improve this and if so, how would you implement that?

Comment: Ok first, I see that `sums` is a 1D array only containing the sums of the rows. It can just replace `sums[i]` as `sum(row)` and there is one less list

Comment: Or i would only calculate that once per row, instead of replacing

Comment: It's gonna take some steps to actually work through this, [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is all about doing this kind of stuff using iterators and list comps

Comment: Also why not just calculate the max value, then iterate and normalize without returning a new array?